# General approach for a parent child relation view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the technical approach to display a parent entity (DropDownFor/ListBoxFor) and its children (razor foreach)?

[image]

Should I create ONE Index.cshtml with the razor code for parent AND children inside?

Just a sidenote: I am using EF with ViewModels and the children are not eager loaded when the customers are retrieved. I load the order explicitly when the customer is selected.

I can not find any tutorials or info about the correct approach it seems nobody is doing that with Razor?

Answer (score 0):

One way is: on DDL's change event, load data with `JSON`.

```
$('#CustomerDDL').change(function (e) {
            url = '@Url.Action("GetCustomerDetails", "Customer")';
            var data = { id: this.value };
            $.post(url, data, function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    var detailsList = result.detailsList;
                    var table = "<table>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < detailsList.length; i++) 
                    {
                        table += "<tr>" + 
                                 "<td> detailsList[i].invoice_number + "</td>" +
                                 "<td> detailsList[i].quantity + "</td>" +
                                 //etc...
                                 "</tr>";
                    }
                    table += "</table>";
                }
                else {
                    var table = "<table> no data </table>";
                }

                $('#DivForShowDetails').html(table);
            });
        });
```

And in `Customer` controller your `LoadCustomerDetails` action:

```
   public ActionResult GetCustomerDetails(int id)
    {
        var result = _ServiceOrRepo.LoadCustomerDetailsById(id);
        if (result != null && result.Count() > 0)
        {
            List<object> detailsList = new List<object>();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                detailsList.Add(new
                {
                    id = item.Id,
                    invoice_number = item.invoice_number,
                    quantity = item.quantity,
                    // etc...
                });
            }

            return Json(new { detailsList = detailsList, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Edit:**

You can use **another way** like this. Main view, for example `Index.cshtml` contains these:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetDetails", "Customer", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "getDetailsResult" }, new { id = "customersForm" }))
{
      @Html.DropDownList("Customer", ViewBag.Customers as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @onchange="CustomerChanged(this.value);" })

      <input type="hidden" id="hiddencustomer" name="customerId" />  

      <noscript>
         //this button will not shown
         <input type="submit" value="" />
      </noscript>                   
}

//results will shown here after form submit.
<div class="detailsSection" id="getDetailsResult">
      @Html.Partial("Selected_Customer_Details", Model)
</div>

<script>
       function CustomerChanged(cId) 
       {
           //take selected customer
           $('#hiddencustomer').val(cId);

           //submit form
           $('#customersForm').submit();
       }
</script>
```

And `Selected_Customer_Details.cshtml` partial view:

```
@model DetailsModel
<h2>@Model.Title/h2>
<table>
   <tr>//your details displaying code goes here... </tr>
<table
```

And in controller you have an `Index` action that contains customers list:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(_ServiceOrRepo.LoadCustomers(), "Id", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

and `GetDetails` action returns `Selected_Customer_Details.cshtml` partial view:

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int id)
{
    DetailsModel model = _ServiceOrRepo.LoadCustomerDetailsById(id);
    return PartialView("Selected_Customer_Details", model);
}
```

Comment: I'd say the result returned from the GetCustomerDetails action should be a partial result to avoid html construction in the javascript. If you do want to go the json data returned and then the markup constructed on the browser then a js templating engine would be a cleaner way forward.

Comment: "I'd say the result returned from the GetCustomerDetails action should be a partial result". I agree to return a PartialView which has the razor orders template

Comment: it is just one way. One can also use Ajax.BeginForm() and results in partial view.

Comment: Can you show more code of your last suggestion wether we think the same?